# When is it a good idea to implement optional functions in a Typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have been implementing the `Foldable` for one data type that I made and I was wondering if I should implement `foldr` and the other optional functions in the typeclass.

I looked into the documentation, but that only explains the functions, not if I should implement it on my own version or if the default version is fine. Then I looked into the implementation, which made things even more complicated since some functions use `#.` instead of `.` to fix some kind of inefficiency, which I'm not sure my implementation would get rid of or how I find out.

I also tried to google it and search it on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find anything relevant unfortunately.

So how do I decide whether or not I should implement the optional functions of the more complicated typeclasses like `Foldable`?

Comment: If they are oprional, then they have default implementation. You can implement them if you want it.

Comment: This is actually quite straightforward: if you think you can write the other functions in ways that are much more efficient than their default implementations in terms of `foldr`, feel free to do so.

Comment: @Alec That's simple to say, but it can be quite hard to tell if my function is actually better than the default implementation, since how a certain function behaves under different kinds of arguments. E.g. strict vs lazy values, functions vs non-functions, infinite vs finite values. So it seems like it would require a lot of time to figure that out, which seems like a lot of work just for deciding if it's worth implementing my own version.

Comment: If you look unfavorably on this analysis, it probably means that implementing more than the default `foldr` would be a premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The example I like (and don't understand why it is not part of the actual definition) is `mconcat` for `Product`. As a reminder

```
class Monoid a where
  mempty :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
```

The `Product` instance looks like

```
instance Num a => Monoid (Product a) where
  mempty = Product 1
  (Product x) `mappend` (Product y) = Product (x * y)
```

Now, with the default `mconcat`, `mconcat (map Product [1..10])` has to multiply all the numbers together to get the final answer of 0. (In fact, with an infinite list, the function never terminates.)

If `mconcat` had been replaced with

```
mconcat = foldr (\acc v -> if v == Product 0 then Product0 else mappend acc v) mempty
```

then `mconcat` could return `Product 0` the first time it sees a `Product 0` in the list.

Comment: This is a good explanation as to why one might want to add more functions with default implementations to typeclasses, but OP is asking about whether to implement functions in an existing typeclass with default implementations.

Comment: I wasn't as explicit as I could have been; this is an example of where you should (and I don't know why the `Product` instance doesn't`) provide a different definition of `mconcat`.

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense - that is a very good point. :)

Comment: This can be done with `mappend (Product 0) _ = Product 0`, no need to get `mconcat` involved